# Stuck in loop form CFRunLoop

Tags: ios, xcode

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
CFSocketRef s;
int connectFlag;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
void receiveDataCilent(CFSocketRef cs, 
                   CFSocketCallBackType type, 
                   CFDataRef address, 
                   const void *data, 
                   void *info)
{  

CFDataRef df = (CFDataRef) data;
int len = CFDataGetLength(df);
if(len <= 0) return;

CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0,len);
UInt8 buffer[len];
NSLog(@"Received %d bytes from socket %d\n", 
      len, CFSocketGetNative(cs));
CFDataGetBytes(df, range, buffer);
NSLog(@"Client received: %s\n", buffer); 
NSLog(@"As UInt8 coding: %@", df);
NSLog(@"len value: %d", len);


}

-(void) clientConnect:(int)sender;{



s = CFSocketCreate(NULL, PF_INET, 
                    SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 
                    kCFSocketDataCallBack, 
                    receiveDataCilent, 
                    NULL);

struct sockaddr_in      sin; 
struct hostent          *host;

memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));

host = gethostbyname("localhost");      

memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr,host->h_length); 

sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(6666);

CFDataRef address;
CFRunLoopSourceRef source;

address = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
CFSocketConnectToAddress(s, address, 0);

CFRelease(address);

source = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, s, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), 
                   source, 
                   kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
CFRelease(source); 
CFRunLoopRun(); 

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if(connectFlag == 0 ){
[self clientConnect:1];
}

}
```

First I'm sorry for  messing the concept of xcode programming and threading programming I'm very new to xcode and I need to finish my game project soon

This code is suppose to connect to server and waiting for message from server. I try and test it and it work fine. In view I have IBAction that can press and change view.

But after I implement it to my main project. It can run but I cannot press any button or do anything. After log it out. It seem it stuck around CFRunLoopRun(); I think it stuck in loop but why when I test it. it not stuck ?

In my project this code is run from another view not from ViewController like I just test.
I don't know why it stuck in my project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run the run loop yourself on the main thread. The main event loop will run it.

Edit: I should say, "within the context of a GUI app". In a command-line tool, you do need to run the run loop yourself.

Comment: You also need to run the runloop yourself on background threads that you create (if they require a runloop).

Comment: Why do you want to? You can use asynchronous networking like `CFSocket` from the main thread just fine.

Comment: Oh I can do it. Thank you very much.